# Panda get cell's index within his column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python programming, pandas module etc. and couldn't find something that works for my problem:
I have a listcomprehension like that:

```
salesCategory1=[df["soldUnits"][???] * df["sellingPrice"][???] for x in df["productCategories"] if x=="category1"]
```

how do I get the index of x, that I can insert it into the question mark? Like the first product with category 1 is on index 9 then it calculates the sales of `df["soldUnits"][9] * df["sellingprice][9]`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this comprehension? What does your Frame look like? Because, given the limited view, it seems like filtering by category and multiplying the columns directly would be a better approach.

Comment: Sorry about that, the Dataframe is out of an excel which has columns like product, store, sellingprice, sold units and product categories. I'll try the approach with the filtering but I'm just so frustrated that I only need the index of x to make the code work, but I can't find any solution to get that index. Like an i for i in range(0,positionOfX) so I can use the i variable in the index of the 2 other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#enumerate) which gives you index numbers:

```
[df["soldUnits"].iloc[n] * df["sellingPrice"].iloc[n] for n, cat in enumerate(df["productCategories"]) if cat == "category1"]
```

Note the use of [`.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if you’re using numbers instead of indexes.

You could do this with indexes, by using [`Series.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
[df["soldUnits"][idx] * df["sellingPrice"][idx] for idx, cat in df["productCategories"].iteritems() if cat == "category1"]
```

However an even more efficient way to do this, and also more expected with pandas, would be to use a boolean indexer (a Series basically) to select the products, and multiply the columns directly:

```
cat1_products = df['productCategories'] == 'category1'
df['soldUnits'][cat1_products] * df['sellingPrice'][cat1_products]
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was the exact solution to my problem! I just needed that index number and couldn't figure out how but 'enumerate()' seems to perfectly work for it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you may want this:

```
df.loc[df["productCategories"]=="category1", ["soldUnits", '"sellingPrice"']].product(axis=1)
```

Comment: This is a great solution for the task too! But the other person had the exact solution for my problem but still thank you very much. Your code is much more efficient than mine, but I was so frustrated that my list comprehension attempt failed on that index problem